# If statement inside a ListView with Eval() or DataBinder.Eval()?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, eval

I have a listview control on an .aspx page. Inside this list view i want to check "Type" property which comes from database. here is the example code :

```
 <ItemTemplate>
         <%# if(Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Type")) == 0){ %>
            <tr class="item">
                <td>
                    <%# Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("WorkDate")).ToShortDateString() %>
                </td>
                <td style="text-align: center;">
                    <%# Eval("SkillName") %>
                </td>
             </tr>
         <%# } else if (Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Type")) == 1) {%>
             <tr class="item">
                <td colspan="2">
                    <strong><%# Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("WorkDate")).ToShortDateString() %></strong>
                </td>
             </tr>
          <% } %>
  </ItemTemplate>
```

As a last resort i tried to user DataBinder.Eval() but i get the exception "Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct". What can i be doing wrong? Writing a function in code-behind isn't an option for me. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: "Writing a function in code-behind isn't an option for me"
Why? There is an ItemDataBound Event where you can do that all easily: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.itemdatabound.aspx

Comment: The problem is with the control statements, they are a no-no in an item template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested, as I don't have Visual Studio available at the moment, but since [HtmlTableRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmltablerow.aspx) has a `Visible` property, the following should work:

```
<tr class="item" runat="server" Visible='<%# Convert.ToInt32(Eval("Type")) == 0 %>'>
    ...
</tr>
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is the full code, made fancy and short.

```
 <ItemTemplate>
         <tr class="item">
            <td colspan="<%# Eval(Container.DataItem,"Type")) == 0 ? 1:2%>">
                <strong><%# Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("WorkDate")).ToShortDateString() %></strong>
            </td>
             <td style="text-align: center;" visible="<%# Eval(Container.DataItem,"Type")) == 1>">
                <%# Eval("SkillName") %>
            </td>
        </tr>
 </ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: this Eval thing would be executed on the server side, correct?

Comment: @HakuKalay - in .NET stuff in `<% %>` and `<%# %>` is evaluated by the scripting system and not sent directly to the browser. When the `#` present it means write the result of evaluating an expression.  When it is not present it is executed by the scripting language (so it can contain branching and loops functionality.)

Answer (score 0):

yes you will have to do some client side scripting though... I would suggest jquery..

you would basically loop through all of the rows in jquery and based on the data in the row you would be able to change the innerhtml of the row object based on the ".item" selector to determine whether it should be in one format or the other.

Comment: No client side scripting is not required -- see @Heinzi for stand way to do this.

Comment: my understanding of the OP's question is that he has two different formats for each line that he would like to implement. if it is one type the format should be 1 way, if its the other type it should be another way. i'm not sure if hiding a row based on type will work unless he is double displaying each record from the data set in the template and turning them off and on in each itteration.

Comment: Heinzi's way is exactly right. No client side scripting is required for this.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what you do, or you can be fancy specific case like my example.